# MongoDB diacriticInSensitive search not showing all accented (words with diacritic mark) rows as expected and vice-versa

Tags: mongodb, search, diacritics, text-search, accent-insensitive

I have a document collection with following structure

```
uid, name
```

With a Index

```
db.Collection.createIndex({name: "text"})
```

It contains following data

```
1, iphone
2, iphóne
3, iphonë
4, iphónë
```

When I am doing text search for `iphone`
I am getting only two records, which is unexpected

```
actual output
--------------
1, iphone
2, iphóne
```

If I search for `iphonë`

```
db.Collection.find( { $text: { $search: "iphonë"} } );

I am getting
---------------------
3, iphonë
4, iphónë
```

But Actually I am expecting following output

```
db.Collection.find( { $text: { $search: "iphone"} } );
db.Collection.find( { $text: { $search: "iphónë"} } );

    Expected output
    ------------------
    1, iphone
    2, iphóne
    3, iphonë
    4, iphónë
```

am I missing something here?
How can I get above expected outputs, with search of `iphone` or `iphónë`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since **mongodb 3.2**, [**text indexes**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) are diacritic insensitive:

> With version 3, text index is diacritic insensitive. That is, the
>   index does not distinguish between characters that contain diacritical
>   marks and their non-marked counterpart, such as é, ê, and e. More
>   specifically, the text index strips the characters categorized as
>   diacritics in [Unicode 8.0 Character Database Prop List](http://www.unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/ucd/PropList.txt).

So the following query should work:

```
db.Collection.find( { $text: { $search: "iphone"} } );
db.Collection.find( { name: { $regex: "iphone"} } );
```

but it looks like there is a bug with dieresis ( ¨ ), even if it's caterorized as diacritic in unicode 8.0 list (issue on JIRA: [SERVER-29918](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29918) )

### Solution

since **mongodb 3.4** you can use [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) which allows you to perform this kind of query :

for example, to get your expected output, run the following query:

```
db.Collection.find({name: "iphone"}).collation({locale: "en", strength: 1})
```

this will output:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "iphone" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "iphône" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "iphonë" }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "iphônë" }
```

in the collation, `strength` is the level of comparaison to perform

- **1** : base character only
- **2** : diacritic sensitive
- **3** : case sensitive + diacritic sensitive

Comment: I have implemented the code above but still matching the exact match, can you help me