# Why does React not display images with diacritical marks in the name?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I am wondering why React does not display images with characters in the name such as: `ą`, `ć`, `ż`, `ł` etc ? In my case they are Polish characters.
I have all filenames stored as path in MongoDB database then display them using `map` function. The status of all images is stored in Redux. All images are placed in the `public` directory. When I copy the file name and paste it to the URL, the browser displays the photo normally, but React itself no longer does. What is the cause of this behavior ? What I tried was trying to pass the filename through the `encodeURI()` function, e.g. `<img src={encodeURI(file.name) />`, but with no positive result.

```
{video.map((file) => (
  <li
    key={file.name}
  >
      <img
        src={file.cover}
        alt={file.name}
      />
  </li>
))}
```

Aciton from Redux:

```
export const moviesList =
  (keyword = '') =>
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: VIDEO_LIST_REQUEST })

      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `/api/video?keyword=${keyword}`,
        config
      )

      dispatch({
        type: VIDEO_LIST_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      })
    } catch (error) {
        ...
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this is a React issue. What does your browser's dev tools say, are the requests e. g. 404ing?

Comment: This won't be a React issue. Look in the browser console to see what's being requested from the server (the exact `src` value), and what responses the server is providing.

Comment: Are you sure `file.cover` has correct value? Show us an actual value for the property.

Comment: How are you querying the data? MongoDB has [some special behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43138610/4756341) when it comes to querying diacritics

Comment: @BrendanBond The author shouldn't be affected by collation in any way as he is not (at least shouldn't) be querying by the actual URLs.

Comment: I did not find any errors in console regarding the photos. Only the message "The character encoding of a clear text document was not declared. When displaying this document in some browser configurations, some characters outside the US-ASCII range (if any) may look incorrect. The file's character encoding must be declared in the transfer protocol, or the file must use a byte order tag as an encoding signature."

Comment: @zhulien "Are you sure file.cover has correct value? Show us an actual value for the property." - Yes, because I have other pictures in my collection, without Polish characters, that display correctly.

Comment: Okay then. Show us a `file` object that contains polish characters in the `cover` property.

Comment: @zhulien https://imgur.com/wZ0KKMi

Comment: @nsog8sm43x You've stated `<img src={encodeURI(file.name) />`. Do you mean `<img src={encodeURI(file.cover)} />`? Maybe a typo? In any case, you shouldn't have any problems opening the image after you encode the URI. Also, as a suggestion, you shouldn't use such characters in the filenames in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in the description. There is a function with the correct parameter in the code. After adding it again I got a 404 error in the console for all missing images.